# Bianchi identity in EMT

Tags: electromagnetism, tensor-calculus, differentiation, calculus

$ ∇_a∇_b F_{ab} =  0 $ ($F_{ab}$ Faraday tensor in EMT.)

proof is given by

> "To see this, assume a Minkowski spacetime for simplicity and adopt
> Cartesian coordinates, so that the covariant derivatives reduce to partial derivatives $\partial_a \partial_b F_{ab}$. The partial derivatives then commute, meaning that $∂_a∂_b$ is symmetric, while $Fab$ is antisymmetric, so that the contraction $\partial_a \partial_b F_{ab}$ must vanish."
> here we have assumed minkowski spacetime,  how will we proceed if we do not assume that it is flat, since covariant derivatives do not commute.

Comment: What don't you understand about the proof?

Comment: Please provide more context...

Comment: You hid your question inside the indented quote.

Comment: *proof is given by* In what textbook? It’s not a proof in curved spacetime.

Answer (score 2):

There are two basic things u need to understand for understanding this argument:

1. The covariant derivative $\nabla_a$ reduces to the partial derivative $\partial_a=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^a}$ in a Minkowski spacetime (Cartesian coordinates),
   $$\nabla_a\rightarrow\partial_a$$
2. The partial derivatives commute, meaning $\partial_a\partial_b=\partial_b\partial_a$ and along with the fact that the EM stress energy tensor is antisymmetric, namely $F_{ab}=-F_{ba}$, results in the vanishing of the identity, since
   $$\partial_a\partial_bF_{ab}=-\partial_a\partial_bF_{ba}\xrightarrow[]{\text{relabel}\ a\rightarrow b}-\partial_b\partial_aF_{ab}=-\partial_a\partial_bF_{ab}$$
   and therefore we reached the conclusion that
   $$\partial_a\partial_bF_{ab}=-\partial_a\partial_bF_{ab}
   \Rightarrow 2\partial_a\partial_bF_{ab}=0$$
   $\underline{\text{note:}}$ upon relabelling things, we do not actually vary our expression, nothing changes because $a,\ b$ are both dummy variables.

This is always the case when indices of symmetric and antisymmetric tensors are contracted ($\partial_a\partial_b$ is a symmetric tensor, whereas $F_{ab}$ is an antisymmetric one).

If anything is unclear, let me know so that I can edit my response.

Comment: I disagree with point 1. For example, Minkowski spacetime in spherical coordinates has non-zero Christoffel symbols, so the covariant derivative does not act as a partial derivative.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I shall edit!!

Comment: The question was “how will we proceed if we do **not** assume that it is flat”.